# getFillForegroundColor() is returning 0 for a coloured cell

Tags: apache-poi

While reading color of a XSSFCell, cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor() is returning 0 even though there is some user defined color in the cell. But i am able to get the non-zero value for few well known colors.

```
 for ( int rowNo=0; rowNo<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNo++){ 
     Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNo); 
     for(int cellNo=0; cellNo<row.getLastCellNum(); cellNo++) { 
       Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNo, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK); 
       CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
       System.out.println("ForegroundColor:"+cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor());
       System.out.println("BackgroundColor:"+cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor()); 
      } 
    }
```

Please suggest on how to read the custom color value from XLSX file.

Comment: Did you check the fill background colour, along with the style?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gagravar.

Comment: for ( int rowNo=0; rowNo<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNo++){
   Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNo);
  for(int cellNo=0; cellNo<row.getLastCellNum(); cellNo++) {
  Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNo, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
  CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
System.out.println("ForegroundColor:"+cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor());
 System.out.println("BackgroundColor:"+cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor());   
 }              
  }

Comment: It's probably better to include the code-snippet in the question itself by using the "edit" functionality of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has two different notions of color, an `indexed` one and a `custom` one. Indexed colors are predefined colors where the color-value is defined by Microsoft. Custom colors store the usual RGB-value triplet.

XSSFCellStyle has different functions depending if you want to read indexed or custom color, e.g. `getFillForegroundColor()` returns the indexed color, `getFillForegroundColorColor()` returns a custom color.

These methods will not try to "convert", so if you have a custom color, the indexed-method will return 0 and if you have an indexed color, requesting the custom color will return null.

See also the related [JavaDoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html).